# string and int concat in c

Tags: c++, arduino

I was wondering if there is any easy way to add a string and an int in c. The catch is that I can't really load a lot of libraries because I am working with an arduino which has a tiny amount of memory.

In short is there any way to add a string and an int together in arduino?

My solution up untill now has been this which is not elegant at all:

```
Serial.print(string);
Serial.print(seperator);
Serial.print(integer);
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: If it works, it's not entirely stupid. That said, `Serial.print(int)` will already be pulling in an integer to string conversion routine anyway, so if you call the same one it uses internally, there won't be any extra overhead.

Comment: I highliy doubt that this code is c.

Comment: @iharob It is using the Arduino's serial library to print to serial port.

Comment: It's c++ for sure. So please remove the c tag.

Comment: @iharob It it neither but fine I changed it to c++.

Comment: No, it's definitely C++.

Comment: I don't see anything inelegant here. It quite readably shows what you output, and unless the print method has high overhead, it will be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to do the conversion just to print the output through
   the serial port, the code you have is probably the best solution,
   even if it doesn't look elegant.
2. If you're using the [String object](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringConstructor) when you say "String," you
   can convert the whole expression into a String object with:

   ```
   string + seperator + String(integer)
   ```

   But the Arduino String object doesn't make the best use of memory
   and there's no reason to do this if you're only printing the result
   to the serial port.
3. Alternatively, you can use a C character array, which makes better
   use of memory, and the itoa function from stdlib, which adds about
   600 bytes. See [printing numbers](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PrintingNumbers).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add two integers with `+`, so all you really need is a way to convert a string to an integer. The simplest is probably `sprintf`.

```
int j;
char const* s;
sprintf(s, "%d", &j);
```

If you don't want to use `sprintf`, you can trivially write your own routine:

```
int stringToInt (char const *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*s != 0)
    {
        i *= 10;
        i += (*s - '0');
        s++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Note that this will return garbage unless `s` contains only a decimal integer expressed in base 10.